# no overload for "button_click" matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Tags: c#, button

I'm trying to remove a line from a file of data and a listBox.  But I'm getting the error: No overload for 'removeButton_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler.'  How can I fix this error?

```
public partial class Message_ReaderMainForm : Form
{
private void validSitesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        removeButton.Visible = true;
        moveButton.Visible = true;
        editButton.Visible = true;

        removeButton_Click(sender, e, validSitesListBox.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, int location)
    {
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("userFile.txt");

        validSitesListBox.Items.RemoveAt(location);
        data.RemoveAt(location);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
        {
            file.WriteLine(data[i].Item1 + " " + data[i].Item2 + " " + data[i].Item3);
        }

    }

}
```

This is the location where the error occurs:

```
 partial class Message_ReaderMainForm
{
        // 
        // removeButton
        // 
        this.removeButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(255, 351);
        this.removeButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
        this.removeButton.Name = "removeButton";
        this.removeButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(59, 21);
        this.removeButton.TabIndex = 5;
        this.removeButton.Text = "Remove";
        this.removeButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // This is where the error is showing up in the code.
        this.removeButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.removeButton_Click);
}
```

Comment: this.removeButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.removeButton_Click);  // Each event can only have 1 method. Put the second one in a function and call it from the event.

Comment: remove 'location' parameter from 'removeButton_Click' method

Answer (score 4):

It's because you have declared it as

```
private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, int location)
```

The `int location` parameter means it doesn't match the `System.EventHandler` delegate definition. You'll need to remove that parameter if you want to use it as an event handler and obtain `location` via some other means.

Answer (score 1):

The event handler signature is not matched, it must be,

```
private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

You cannot pass aditional parameters in the existing delegate that is `EventHandler`

The actual signature of EventHandler is,

```
public delegate void EventHandler (Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

You cannot change it...

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

in your case, you can use ListBox.SelectedIndex property (validSitesListBox.SelectedIndex )instead of Location

- i don't undestand why do you call removeButton_Click in validSitesListBox_SelectedIndexChanged. it's an event, it's trigered "automatically" when you click on "removeButton".